Compute: $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\pi x}\text{Ei}(x)dx$
I thought this was divergent, but apparently WolframAlpha says that there is an actual answer to this.
I am very lost to how someone could apply laplace to this because the bound is different:
$$\mathcal{L}\left \{ \int_{-t}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx \right \}$$
And I don't know how to approach this with integration by parts because it leads to this weird limit:
$$\frac{1}{a}\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\text{Ei}(ax)-\text{Ei}(x).$$
Is there a elementary way to go about this without knowing too much about special functions?

OMG, nevermind, I just realized something. Notice, by definition of Ei(x),
$$\frac{1}{a}\lim_{x\rightarrow0}(\text{Ei}((a-1)x)-\text{Ei}(x))=\frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-(a-1)x}-e^{-x}}{x}dx$$
By Frullani integral,
$$=\frac{(0-1)}{a}\ln(a-1)=\boxed{-\frac{\ln(a-1)}{a}}$$
